# type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, dart

**Here is my code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WeatherScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  WeatherScreen({this.parseWeatherData});
  final dynamic parseWeatherData;

  @override
  _WeatherScreenState createState() => _WeatherScreenState();
}

class _WeatherScreenState extends State<WeatherScreen> {
  late String cityName;
  late int temp;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    updateData(widget.parseWeatherData);
  }

  void updateData(dynamic weatherData) {
    double temp2 = weatherData['main']['temp'];
    temp = temp2.round();
    cityName = weatherData['name'];

    print(temp);
    print(cityName);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                '$cityName',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Text(
                '$temp',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here is the error:**

```dart
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building WeatherScreen(dirty, state: _WeatherScreenState#c7222):
type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'function result'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `late num temp;`

Answer (score 0):

change `late int temp` to `late double temp` and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

replace double to var

```
double temp2 ...
```

to

```
var temp2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use late and in parsing to Text use .toString method